# Returning word when looking for longest word instead of number of characters

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

So, I am working on a function that looks for the longest word in a string. However I can't find how to console.log the actual word and not the value of the number of characters it has. Here is my function:

```
function longestWord(text) {
var textSplit = text.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < textSplit.length; i++) {
    var wordLength = textSplit[i].length;
};
console.log(Math.max(wordLength));
}
longestWord("I dislike taking recent microwaves");
```

Comment: So hold a reference to the largest word.

Comment: words.sort(function(a,b){return a.length-b.length}).pop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you detect that the current one is longer than your longest one, save it.

```
function longestWord(text) {
        var longestWordLength = 0;
        var longestWordString = '';

        var textSplit = text.split(" ");

        for (var i = 0; i < textSplit.length; i++) {
            var word = textSplit[i];
            var wordLength = word.length 
            if (longestWordLength < wordLength) {
                longestWordLength = wordLength;
                longestWordString = word;
            }
        };
        console.log(longestWordString);
    }
    longestWord("I dislike taking recent microwaves");
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dqqrerh/).

Comment: Yes, but was following @Fyxerz's approach and wanted to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reducer:

```
var longestWord = function(str) {
  return str.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return x.length > acc.length ? x : acc
  },'')
}

longestWord("I dislike taking recent microwaves"); //=> microwaves
```